# How do I parse data from certain http website?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to create an iOS app for my basketball league to make it easier for users to access their data. My problem is if I can't parse the data from the url to JSON objects through AlamoFire? Can anyone show me how to do this or a point me to the direction towards how to do this?

When I parse the data through [JSON FORMATTER](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), I'm reading JSON data from the URL with key values like this which is what I want

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
renderEvent({  
id:9918737,
start:'2016-12-11T19:00:00',
end:'2016-12-11T20:00:00',
title:'INGLORIOUS BALLERS vs  STRICTLY BUCKETS',
description:'',
location:'GYM 2',
type:'c',
icon:'/z/images/icons/star.gif',
href:''
});
</script>
```

but when I parse data through AlamoFire, I get an error.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Start Parsing Data")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Alamofire.request("http://www.eteamz.com/filhoopshouston/index.cfm?subsite=6674630").responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }

            if response.result.error != nil {
                print("ERROR \(response.result.error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: He or she is only trying to return a response from Alamofire.  So use of SwiftyJSON won't change a thing.

Comment: try to use .response instead of .responseJSON because the server reply is not fully JSON?